NestJs: Setup passport strategy for Linked authentication using OpenId
I am trying to setup "Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect" in my nestjs application. I tried to setup using passport-linkedin-oauth2 but was always getting you dont have access to profile data even though my scope has the permission. Did anyone setup the new linked openid connect using NestJs and passport strategy. Any help or tips in resolving this issue please. Thanks.

Providing some code, would help.
